# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory in angular

Tags: angular, npm, angular5, angular6

I'm getting this error after updating npm

Failed to compile.

./node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/user/pitalent/ngPitalent/node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js'

How to solve this?

Comment: Try do this:
1) remove folder: node_modules;
2) remove file: package-lock.json;
3) run: npm instal.
Hope this help.

Comment: @DmitriyIvanko This did not work for me.

Comment: @Shadowvail 1) try check package.json dependencies and devDependencies maybe you miss some library 2) If it is not help, then create repo on GitHub and share link.